# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^n$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $(a_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence of
real numbers such that $a_0\geq 1$ and $a_n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty.$

The following limit is always convergent or which condition may be added on $(a_n)$ the given limit to be convergent?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^n$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint :
Write the limit as $$\left[\left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{a_n} \right]^{\frac{n}{a_n}}.$$
The limit inside the bracket is $\frac{1}{e}$; what must the value of $n/{a_n}$, as $n\to \infty$, be, to ensure that the limit converges?

Answer (score 2):

Since $y = \mathrm{e}^x$ is a continuous function and$$
\left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right)^n = \exp\left(n \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right)\right),
$$
then$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right)^n \ \text{exists} \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right) \ \text{exists}.
$$
Given that $a_n \to \infty \ (n \to \infty)$, thus$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{a_n} = 0 \Longrightarrow \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right) \sim -\frac{1}{a_n} \ (n \to \infty).
$$
Therefore,$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right) \ \text{exists} \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{a_n} \ \text{exists}.
$$

Comment: Condition on $a_n$ is not sufficient for $\lim_{n\to\infty} n/a_n$ to be convergent?

Comment: What condition exactly is it?

Comment: Some small comments, it is important that $e^x$ is injective. For instance $a_n^2$ can exist and $a_n$ may not exist. Also, when you say $$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right)^n \ \text{exists} \Longleftrightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{a_n}\right) \ \text{exists}.
$$ The left limit  converges to $0$ when the right limit converges to $-\infty$, and the left limit converges to $\infty$ when the right limit converges to $\infty$

Comment: $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing and $a_0\geq 1$ and $a_n\rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: @andii That's not sufficient and there're counterexamples.